# Javascript not pulling an attr value correctly

Tags: jquery

For some reason whenever I click enter I get an alertbox with undefined appearing. My script should be getting the "rel" attr and then outputting it to the alertbox. Any ideas as to why this isn't happening?

My jQuery:

```
// process addComment()
jQuery(".textbox1").keydown(function(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        addComment(this);
    }
});

function addComment(e) {
    var id = jQuery(e).attr("rel");
    alert(id);
}
```

My Html:

```
<input placeholder="Write a comment..." id="commentBox-<?php echo $row->idwallPosts; ?>" class="textbox1" style="width: 423px">
```

Comment: @Michael, can you please either explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do (e.g. "When the user clicks 'enter' in an input element, I want to fetch the 'rel' attribute of an 'a' element and ...") or provide a bit more of your HTML?

Comment: Also, you're giving us the PHP source. If you provide the final output markup (i.e. view source and copy+paste), it'll be easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I haven't written the PHP yet. Once I get the value I'll be sending that through JSON to the PHP script, but I haven't got to that point yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line `addComment(this);` you pass the input object to your function. The object 'input' doesn't have a rel attribute. I assume you want to get the id. Please try:

```
    var id = jQuery(e).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 9):

There doesn't seem to be any `rel` attribute on your `input` tag. I can see `placeholder`, `id`, `class` and `style` but no traces of `rel` whatsoever.

Comment: var id = jQuery(e).attr("rel"); - its this line

Comment: @Michael, that *gets* the value of the rel attribute. But there *is* no rel attribute in your *markup*.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying: <a class="link-font1 commentLink" id="commentLink" rel="<?php echo $row->idwallPosts; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)" style="width: 138px">

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby, no, he is not saying that at all. You need a `rel` attribute. `rel`, not `href` because that's what you are using in your script. So either add a **`rel`** attribute on your input: `<input rel="foo_bar" ...>` or change your script so that you use some of the already existing attributes such as `id`.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: but you're looking for the 'rel' attribute on an 'input' element, not an 'a'.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, so on my input I have this value: commentBox-<?php echo $row->idwallPosts; ?> which does the same thing as rel only it adds commentBox. What I've done in the past is something similar to this: jQuery("#commentBox-"+id). Would this work?

Comment: What you have shown is an id selector. Yes, this will work assuming you have passed the same id on your input as on your script. But I think you want to use the rel attribute: `<input rel="<?php echo $row->" ...>` and then in your script `var row = jQuery(e).attr('rel');`.

Comment: Am I able to add 2 rel attributes to a script?

Comment: No that would be ambiguous. But you could pass a JSON encoded variable into the rel attribute containing multiple values that you will be able to parse back into its constituent parts. For example `<input rel="{foo:'bar', baz: 'bazinga'}" ...>` and in your script: `var data = $.parseJSON($(e).attr(rel)); alert(data.baz);`.

Comment: I've got it working. I've used islandmyth's approach. Thanks for your help.